# How to run a timer continually? (Do not start from the beginning, when yo do refresh)

Tags: javascript, timer

I have my code of timer that only alert when minutes and seconds are 0:

```
status = false;
hour_to_start = some_value; // THIS VALUE IS PUT FOR OTHER PERSON
min = 15; //THIS VALUE IS PUT FOR ANOTHER PERSON
seg = 60;
function timecamisa(){
    if (seg > 0){
    seg--;
}else{
    if(seg==0){
        min--;
        seg=60;
    }
}
if(min == 0 && seg==0){
    // END - STOP ALL
    min= 0;
    seg = 0;
    status = true;
}
var timer = min + ' minutos ' + seg + ' segundos';
document.getElementById("times-get").innerHTML = timer;
if(status != true){
    setTimeout("timecamisa()",1000)//This reload this function (timecamisa())
}else{
    alert("END!");
}
```

In my HTML i have a `<span id="times-get">` where print the timer.
BUT, when i press F5 my timer return to the beginning and does not continue where you left off... So, How to do this? Anyone have a example?

My target is that my timer work with my variable 'hour_to_start' and 'min' where.. This timer displays the countdown from my variable 'hour_to_start' in 'x' 'min' (my other variable). And when the variable MIN is 0(ie, complete the mins).. Alert anything.

---

### UPDATE!

OK, i do it with Jquery Plugin countdown Timer.. Is very useful for more than 1 timers.

Now, mi problem is.. when i change the time of my computer, this timer change too.

How to avoid changing my timer when you change the time, date and / or time of my machine?

Comment: Use cookies to store value onunload the reset it onload

Comment: Don't pass strings to setTimeout, pass the function directly: `setTimeout(timeCamisa, 1000)`

Answer (score 0):

You will need to get the time from either your server or from some remote server (e.g. via a javascript from someone else's server).  If you get the time using javascript it will always depend on the clock of the user's machine.

Comment: Uuhhmmm, I use PHP Language.. If i get the Time of Server by php and pass it to my file javascript, that would solve the problem?